# Linq-to-sql using GroupBy and return record satisfying condition

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a query for which I'll provide the relevant part of it

```cs
IQueryable<a> query;

query.Where(dbEntry => dbEntry.ConditionId == id)
    .Where(dbEntry => dbEntry.PharmacyStockBBD.Value > NO_BEFORE_THAN)
    .GroupBy(dbEntry => dbEntry.ProductId, pair => pair, (_e1, _e2) => new
    {
        ProductId = _e1,
        Entry = _e2.OrderBy(pair => pair.PharmacyStockBBD).First()
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

I'm getting

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: (p.Id), 
> ElementSelector:new { 
>     PharmacyStockId = (ProjectionBindingExpression: PharmacyStockId), 
>     PharmacyStockBBD = (ProjectionBindingExpression: PharmacyStockBBD), 
>     ProductId = (ProjectionBindingExpression: ProductId), 
>     ProductName = (ProjectionBindingExpression: ProductName), 
>     ChildProductId = (ProjectionBindingExpression: ChildProductId), 
>     IcnId = (ProjectionBindingExpression: IcnId), 
>     IcnName = (ProjectionBindingExpression: IcnName), 
>     PharmacyStock_ProductBoxes = (ProjectionBindingExpression: PharmacyStock_ProductBoxes), 
>     .....
>  }
> )
>     .OrderBy(pair => pair.PharmacyStockBBD)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> ```
>
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

What I'm trying to do is group by ProductId, but get only the record having the PharmacyStockBBD as Min.

I've treid

```cs
Entry = _e2.Min(pair => pair.PharmacyStockBBD)
```

which works, but I need the whole _e2.

Also I know that GroupBy will get executed on the sql engine (MSSSQL) and I also knwo that it needs some aggregate function, but I need the entire record set for which `PharmacyStockBBD` is min.

Comment: *that GroupBy will get executed on the sql engine* actually that particular query won't get executed in the db, and that's the crux of the error ..

Comment: can  you give like more context ? and maybe an example from which I can use ?

Comment: The error means "the query you have written cannot be translated to sql and run on the db server, so your options are to rewrite it in a way that can be translated to sql, or download all the data out of the db server and then LINQ will loop through it and do the grouping in c#". In the old days the latter happened automatically, which was fairly terrible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most efficient way to do this would be with raw sql;

```
    context.YourTable.FromSqlInterpolated(@"
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY PharmacyStockBBD) rn
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE 
    PharmacyStockId > {NO_BEFORE_THAN}
) x
WHERE rn = 1")
```

You can compose on top of this (include more tables etc

I'm not sure where you want to do the ConditionId check; it does make a difference. If you do it in the inner query, then you'll find all products of that condition, then number them from 1 and find the min product on that condition. If you do it in the outer query, you'll find all products regardless of condition, number them and then discard all those not in the condition. Where you put it depends on whether the first product will be in the condition you want

In essence, do you want to "filter for condition, then take the first" -> put it in the inner where, or do you want "take all the firsts, then filter them for condition" -> put it in the outer where